# Terminating unused wiring in electrical box

Tags: circuit-breaker

I am upgrading my electrical box with more circuits, and circuit breakers. I would like terminate all the unused circuits wires in the electrical box panel with dummy circuit breakers rather than leave them dangling in the box. I would then terminate the unused wires in the attic within an enclosed terminal block in the attic. When I need to add another circuit in the future, all I have to do is run the circuit from the terminal bock, and replace the dummy circuit breaker with a real one. This avoids the hassle of running a new wire into the panel from the attic, and crowding the panel with unorganized new wiring, etc. I rather do it all upfront. Is there any problems with this configuration other than code issues?

Comment: What wiring method were you planning to use for the run from the panel to the attic, and how many circuits were you planning to run this way?

Comment: What is a dummy circuit breaker? Where is this?

Comment: Jim asks a lot of questions, but "dummy circuit breaker" is new to me too. Only thing I can think is a circuit breaker that fills an empty hole in the panel.  I just use real live breakers for that.

Comment: Also, what make and model is your breaker box?

Comment: @Harper -- at least for QO boxes, there is [such a thing as a dummy breaker](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/faqs/FA103071/) -- it's a QO1DB if you're keeping score at home.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel but does it actually *accept a wire*?

Comment: @Harper -- that's a good question, actually -- it may not, but I'm not 100% sure on that since I don't have one in front of me to try to jam some THHN into :P

Comment: Why not just use a real circuit breaker and keep it turned off then when the time comes to add the circuit, complete the wiring from the attic and flip on the breaker

Comment: Romex 12 gage. The Square D panel will have 42 circuits at 200 Amps. I found Square D makes a dummy circuit breaker part number QO1DB, but Square D doesn't show how its hooked up. It may just be a filler plug used in-place of the hole plate that covers the circuit breaker slot. Anyway, I rather not have terminated wires dangling in the panel. Anyone have another neat solution? Another solution is fill all unused slots with 20 amp circuit breakers, and terminate the ones not used in the attic with a terminal block enclosure which is an expensive solution! The dummy circuit breaker = about $20.

Comment: Here is the link for the dummy circuit breaker. https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/QO1DB/circuit-breaker-filler/

Comment: @AlaskaMan because when someone sees a off breaker while there is an electrical issue (the most common reason to look at the panel) the first instinct is to turn it on.

Comment: According to the [Catalog](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Catalog&p_File_Name=0730CT9801.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=0730CT9801) on the site you linked to you can also get handle accessories which can lock a breaker into the OFF position (ex. [the QO1LO](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/QO1LO/load-center-clamp-qo/)). You could put in proper breakers and wire them up fully and then just add the clamps to ensure they can't be accidentally switched ON. (Though I'm not from the USA so I don't know if that would be up to code?)

Comment: @AlaskaMan that won't do, because it relies on correct *procedure* to prevent  a malfunction (the unattached wires at the far end arcing).  Similar to generator interlocks, procedures are insufficient.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, real breakers are cheaper than the dummy.  A real 15/20A breaker is $8.

Comment: Can't put just any circuit breaker. It's a Square D plug on neutral panel.

Comment: Harper and ratchet freak, the OP indicated that they were going to terminate the wires in the attic into an *enclosed terminal block*.  I.E. not leave bare wires in a box in the attic. If the breaker gets turned  on Is there a risk in having  a live load going into a terminal block ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan -- the issue is that terminal blocks are universally *component recognized*, with the RU (Rather Useless to us) mark.  He needs to either use *listed* splicer-type power distribution blocks for this, or use wire connectors listed to UL 486A-B and mounted into suitable carriers

Comment: @AlwaysLearning -- are you talking about a *QO* panel or a *Homeline* panel? Also, what were you planning to run between the panel and the attic-box, and when you say "enclosed terminal block", what do you mean by that?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning correct, you can only use breakers either *UL-Listed* or *UL-Classified* for the panel.  For instance, in Homeline you can only use SqD Homeline (UL listed) or Eaton CL (UL classified). Not Eaton BR.

Comment: It's a Homeline panel. I called Synder and the dummy is just a dummy with no connection to terminate the wire. Also, it doesn't fit the panel either. The solution for this configuration is probably to connect the wires to unused circuit breakers, and use clamps (QO1LO) to show the circuit breaker is not in use along with a label "Not In USE". The terminal & load distribution block(s) will be UL listed as per code. Remember, this configuration needs to be permitted and inspected. If I decide to go with this solution, I'll submit drawings for review before I commit any funds.

Comment: Terminal and load distribution blocks normally don't come with an enclosure (junction box). Per code, any connection of wires needs to be enclosed, so I will have to put the wire connections in an enclosure regardless how I connect the wires.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning -- what sort of cabling or wire/conduit system do you plan to run from the panel to the attic?

Comment: Romex from the back of panel into the attic through the wall. The wall will be covered up and finished with stucco.

Comment: The new panel is rated for outdoors.

Comment: How many circuits are you trying to set up this way?

Comment: All circuits in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

### Cap off hot and neutral

The hot(s) and neutral wires should be capped off and laid in the panel somewhere out of the way.   Don't attach even the neutral; neutral can be a live wire in certain edge conditions.  You can attach ground, however.

How long to leave the wires? Long enough so **every hot *and neutral* can reach every breaker space in the panel**.  This should be standard operating procedure for every circuit anyway*.  Neutral is one of these because AFCI/GFCI.

* which is incompatible with the "Captain Snippy" method of making wires minimum length for an "ultra-neat panel" -- but you don't *actually* get brownie points for that.  You get brownie points for a functional panel.

Comment: It's an option, but tends to get messy overtime. The above approach increases the touch points in the panel, No offence to electricians, but I rather not pay an electrician to clean up my panel every time I need to add a single circuit, or worst create a mess overtime. I am looking for the best functional solution that is extremely efficient to add circuits, and avoids the spaghetti panel I have now. I appreciate the advise though, and may have no choice, but go in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

### You need the correct parts

The main Code issue with your plan is that your enclosed terminal block needs to be UL listed *as an assembly* in order to be acceptable to the AHJ; since terminal blocks are UL *recognized components*, they are Rather Useless to us by themselves.  Fortunately, there are enclosure-mounted terminal blocks that meet the above constraint available through a couple of vendors; the most useful one for your application is a [McMaster-Carr 3691T14](https://www.mcmaster.com/3691t14), as it provides room for 10 hots and their corresponding neutrals, and can handle a mix of 15A and 20A branch circuits.  You'll have to holesaw some 1/2" trade size (7/8" actual size) knockouts in the sides for NM cable clamps to get the cables in and out of this box, use some knockout plugs to plug the KOs in the ends, and squeeze a pair of [Penn-Union NA-412](https://www.galco.com/buy/Penn-Union/NA-412?source=googleshopping&utm_source=adwords&utm_campaign=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5Pibv6b85gIVi4bACh3RWwZOEAYYASABEgJYhfD_BwE) ground bars, linked by a piece of 10AWG bare copper wire and mounted to the box using 1/4-28 self-tapping screws, into the box to land the equipment grounding conductors to.

For 30A and larger circuits, if you wish to carry this approach to larger sizes, your best bet is to get a bog-standard NEMA 1 pull box from your local electrical supply house and mount some UL listed, 14-4AWG, power distribution (splicer/reducer) blocks in it; while they take up a fair bit of space (3/4" to 1" of width per pole), you won't need nearly as many poles here as you would if you tried this for every circuit under the sun, so the box size can stay semi-reasonable here.  You'll need to whack another ground bar in this box, too; for a reasonable circuit count, another Penn-Union NA-412 will do the trick, or if you need something larger, you can use its bigger brother, the NA-413.  Again, these mount to the enclosure with 1/4-28 self-tapping screws; you'll also need screws to mount the power distribution blocks (or the DIN rail they're attached to) to the enclosure, although these can be ordinary sheet-metal screws.